# split one column into multiple columns by checking the condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with following format,

```
ID | Marks   | Maths | Science | Grade
1  | 72_93_A |       |         | A
2  | 43_B    |       |         | B
```

Now I need to split the Marks columns string with delimiter as _ and insert values in Maths and Science columns. Also If the Marks columns data has three tokens (72_93_A) then I need to update both Maths and Science columns else I need to update only Maths column. I need output as mentioned below,

```
ID | Marks   | Maths | Science | Grade
1  | 72_93_A |  72   |    93   | A
2  | 43_B    |   43  |         | B
```

Can someone help me on this conditional update scenario.

Comment: What database are you in? You need this for all 4? Also, what have you tried to solve your own problem or are just waiting us to do it for you?

Comment: I'm on Oracle db. I tried with SUBSTRING_INDEX getting which is not updating properly. will post that you

Comment: Please edit the question and fix tagging and title. Don't say "in SQL Server" if you want it in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    regexp_substr(Marks, '([^_]+)(_[^_]+){2}$', 1, 1, null, 1) as Maths,
    regexp_substr(Marks, '([^_]+)(_[^_]+){1}$', 1, 1, null, 1) as Science,
    regexp_substr(Marks, '([^_]+)(_[^_]+){0}$', 1, 1, null, 1) as Grade
from . . .
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`regexp_substr`**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm) to perform the update:

```
update your_table
set Maths = regexp_substr(marks, '\d+', 1, 1),
    Science = regexp_substr(marks, '\d+', 1, 2)
where Maths is null
    or science is null;
```

`\d+` matches one or more digits and 4th parameter is the occurrence.